# How do I insert values in a table using inner join?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to insert data into table1.col1 using following query.

```
INSERT INTO table1 t1( t1.col1)  
SELECT t2.col1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.col2= t2.col2;
```

Apparently, it wouldn't work(flawed logic maybe). How can I achieve similar results.
Let me know if I don't make sense.

Comment: What do you think the value of `t1.col2` is?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how is that relevant. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You don't "insert into a column" - do you maybe want to _update_ the column of an existing row?

Comment: Yes. That is what I intend to do.

Comment: Then use update query?

Comment: Well I feel stupid now. What was I thinking, smh.
I feel so ashamed.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT t2.col1 
FROM table2 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 on t1.col2= t2.col2;

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT t2.col1
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2
WHERE t1.col2= t2.col2;

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a `MERGE` statement with `MATCHED`(*for already existing rows in table1*)  and
`NOT MATCHED`(*for rows not inserted into table1 yet*) options :

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
  USING table2 t2
    ON (t1.col2 = t2.col2)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.col1 = t2.col1
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (col1,col2)
    VALUES (t2.col1, t2.col2);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34972/6)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was not looking to insert but to update...stupid question I know :)
This is what I was looking for.

```
update table1 t1 set t1.col1 = (select t2.col1 from table2 t2 where t1.col2 = t2.col2);
```

Comment: Then delete the whole question and start a new post with your actual question.

Comment: I wanted to but I can't. Stackoverflow would not let me. So, I posted the solution instead.